# Backup to Azure Blob Failing with Hallengren Framework

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, ola-hallengren, azure-vm

We are running IAAS VMs in Azure using SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU2.  We are backing up to blob storage using a URL, and the errors received are shown below and described in the MS Connect URL provided.  The defect is marked as corrected in the CU that we are running.

> 1117(The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.)

- https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3119350

According to the article, the workaround is to specific `MAXTRANSFERSIZE`. When I provide this parameter(`@MaxTransferSize = 4194304`), the job starts failing with the error

> The value for the parameter @MaxTransferSize is not supported.

I dug into the stored procedure to find the “OR” condition (`@MaxTransferSize IS NOT NULL AND @URL IS NOT NULL`).  The complete line from the stored procedure is shown below.  Was there a reason for this last condition to be added as Microsoft is recommending this use.  I temporarily commented out that condition and the job succeeded.

```
IF @MaxTransferSize < 65536 OR 
   @MaxTransferSize > 4194304 OR 
   @MaxTransferSize % 65536 > 0 OR 
   (@MaxTransferSize > 1048576 AND @BackupSoftware = 'SQLBACKUP') OR 
   (@MaxTransferSize IS NOT NULL AND @BackupSoftware = 'SQLSAFE') OR 
   (@MaxTransferSize IS NOT NULL AND @URL IS NOT NULL)
```

I’m wondering if this last condition should be removed.

Comment: ["BLOCKSIZE and MAXTRANSFERSIZE are supported for block blobs. They are not supported for page blobs."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url) I don't recall reading this distinction before, it might be a newer feature? I thought that option was flat out incompatible.  You can open an issue for Ola on his [github](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution) (though I'm not so sure he looks at it often).

Comment: What type of storage account..."storage" or "blob"

Comment: The previous comments apply. This is an issue with Page vs Block blobs, and nothing to do with Ola's code.

Answer (score 2):

I have added support for BLOCKSIZE, and MAXTRANSFERSIZE, when backing up to Azure Blob Storage block blobs (using Shared Access Signature).

https://ola.hallengren.com/versions.html